# Same code run in JSFiddle, but with bug in .html

Tags: jquery, html, jsfiddle

I am trying to update a clock using jQuery and the code is working fine in JSFiddle [(link here)](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ma961zw2/), but when I pass it to `.html` the "hours" and "minutes" options becomes "0". See the code below:

```
<ul>
    <li class='hours'>
        <select>
            <option value=0>00</option>
            <option value=1>01</option>
            <option value=2>02</option>
            <option value=3>03</option>
            <option value=4>04</option>
            <option value=5>05</option>
            <option value=6>06</option>
            <option value=7>07</option>
            <option value=8>08</option>
            <option value=9>09</option>
            <option value=10>10</option>
            <option value=11>11</option>
            <option value=12>12</option>
            <option value=13>13</option>
            <option value=14>14</option>
            <option value=15>15</option>
            <option value=16>16</option>
            <option value=17>17</option>
            <option value=18>18</option>
            <option value=19>19</option>
            <option value=20>20</option>
            <option value=21>21</option>
            <option value=22>22</option>
            <option value=23>23</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class='point'>:</li>
    <li class='min'>
        <select>
            <option value=0>00</option>
            <option value=1>01</option>
            <option value=2>02</option>
            <option value=3>03</option>
            <option value=4>04</option>
            <option value=5>05</option>
            <option value=6>06</option>
            <option value=7>07</option>
            <option value=8>08</option>
            <option value=9>09</option>
            <option value=10>10</option>
            <option value=11>11</option>
            <option value=12>12</option>
            <option value=13>13</option>
            <option value=14>14</option>
            <option value=15>15</option>
            <option value=16>16</option>
            <option value=17>17</option>
            <option value=18>18</option>
            <option value=19>19</option>
            <option value=20>20</option>
            <option value=21>21</option>
            <option value=22>22</option>
            <option value=23>23</option>
            <option value=24>24</option>
            <option value=25>25</option>
            <option value=26>26</option>
            <option value=27>27</option>
            <option value=28>28</option>
            <option value=29>29</option>
            <option value=30>30</option>
            <option value=31>31</option>
            <option value=32>32</option>
            <option value=33>33</option>
            <option value=34>34</option>
            <option value=35>35</option>
            <option value=36>36</option>
            <option value=37>37</option>
            <option value=38>38</option>
            <option value=39>39</option>
            <option value=40>40</option>
            <option value=41>41</option>
            <option value=42>42</option>
            <option value=43>43</option>
            <option value=44>44</option>
            <option value=45>45</option>
            <option value=46>46</option>
            <option value=47>47</option>
            <option value=48>48</option>
            <option value=49>49</option>
            <option value=50>50</option>
            <option value=51>51</option>
            <option value=52>52</option>
            <option value=53>53</option>
            <option value=54>54</option>
            <option value=55>55</option>
            <option value=56>56</option>
            <option value=57>57</option>
            <option value=58>58</option>
            <option value=59>59</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class='point'>:</li>
    <li class='sec'>
        <select>
            <option value=0>00</option>
            <option value=1>01</option>
            <option value=2>02</option>
            <option value=3>03</option>
            <option value=4>04</option>
            <option value=5>05</option>
            <option value=6>06</option>
            <option value=7>07</option>
            <option value=8>08</option>
            <option value=9>09</option>
            <option value=10>10</option>
            <option value=11>11</option>
            <option value=12>12</option>
            <option value=13>13</option>
            <option value=14>14</option>
            <option value=15>15</option>
            <option value=16>16</option>
            <option value=17>17</option>
            <option value=18>18</option>
            <option value=19>19</option>
            <option value=20>20</option>
            <option value=21>21</option>
            <option value=22>22</option>
            <option value=23>23</option>
            <option value=24>24</option>
            <option value=25>25</option>
            <option value=26>26</option>
            <option value=27>27</option>
            <option value=28>28</option>
            <option value=29>29</option>
            <option value=30>30</option>
            <option value=31>31</option>
            <option value=32>32</option>
            <option value=33>33</option>
            <option value=34>34</option>
            <option value=35>35</option>
            <option value=36>36</option>
            <option value=37>37</option>
            <option value=38>38</option>
            <option value=39>39</option>
            <option value=40>40</option>
            <option value=41>41</option>
            <option value=42>42</option>
            <option value=43>43</option>
            <option value=44>44</option>
            <option value=45>45</option>
            <option value=46>46</option>
            <option value=47>47</option>
            <option value=48>48</option>
            <option value=49>49</option>
            <option value=50>50</option>
            <option value=51>51</option>
            <option value=52>52</option>
            <option value=53>53</option>
            <option value=54>54</option>
            <option value=55>55</option>
            <option value=56>56</option>
            <option value=57>57</option>
            <option value=58>58</option>
            <option value=59>59</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- JavaScript Includes -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        digitalClock();
    });

    function digitalClock() {
        hrs = $(".hours option")
        min = $(".min option")
        sec = $(".sec option")

        var _updateTime = function() {
            s = new Date().getUTCSeconds();
            m = new Date().getUTCMinutes();
            h = new Date().getUTCHours();
            sec.removeAttr("selected").eq(s).attr("selected", "");
            min.removeAttr("selected").eq(m).attr("selected", "");
            hrs.removeAttr("selected").eq(h).attr("selected", "");
        };

        setInterval(_updateTime, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, is exactly same code, but the clock runs correctly in JSFiddle, but stay 00:00:00 in web browser html. Can you explain me what is the problem?

Comment: Why not check the console and see what the problem is?

Comment: In JSFiddle you're using jQuery 3.1.1, but in your code you're using jQuery 1.10.1.

Comment: Console shows the correct value to time and if you see the html code, the option has attribute selected, but in the select box the value is 0... if you could copy and paste this code and see by yourself, maybe the same bug will appear to you

Comment: check if your html is loading jquery `$` correctly

Comment: Thank you pan.goth the problem is a bug in jQuery, but it was fixed in 3.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your jquery...

Change

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this html is working for me, I've just added `html` and `body` tags to yours.

```
<html>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li class='hours'>
            <select>
            <option value=0>00</option>
            <option value=1>01</option>
            <option value=2>02</option>
            <option value=3>03</option>
            <option value=4>04</option>
            <option value=5>05</option>
            <option value=6>06</option>
            <option value=7>07</option>
            <option value=8>08</option>
            <option value=9>09</option>
            <option value=10>10</option>
            <option value=11>11</option>
            <option value=12>12</option>
            <option value=13>13</option>
            <option value=14>14</option>
            <option value=15>15</option>
            <option value=16>16</option>
            <option value=17>17</option>
            <option value=18>18</option>
            <option value=19>19</option>
            <option value=20>20</option>
            <option value=21>21</option>
            <option value=22>22</option>
            <option value=23>23</option>
        </select>
        </li>
        <li class='point'>:</li>
        <li class='min'>
            <select>
            <option value=0>00</option>
            <option value=1>01</option>
            <option value=2>02</option>
            <option value=3>03</option>
            <option value=4>04</option>
            <option value=5>05</option>
            <option value=6>06</option>
            <option value=7>07</option>
            <option value=8>08</option>
            <option value=9>09</option>
            <option value=10>10</option>
            <option value=11>11</option>
            <option value=12>12</option>
            <option value=13>13</option>
            <option value=14>14</option>
            <option value=15>15</option>
            <option value=16>16</option>
            <option value=17>17</option>
            <option value=18>18</option>
            <option value=19>19</option>
            <option value=20>20</option>
            <option value=21>21</option>
            <option value=22>22</option>
            <option value=23>23</option>
            <option value=24>24</option>
            <option value=25>25</option>
            <option value=26>26</option>
            <option value=27>27</option>
            <option value=28>28</option>
            <option value=29>29</option>
            <option value=30>30</option>
            <option value=31>31</option>
            <option value=32>32</option>
            <option value=33>33</option>
            <option value=34>34</option>
            <option value=35>35</option>
            <option value=36>36</option>
            <option value=37>37</option>
            <option value=38>38</option>
            <option value=39>39</option>
            <option value=40>40</option>
            <option value=41>41</option>
            <option value=42>42</option>
            <option value=43>43</option>
            <option value=44>44</option>
            <option value=45>45</option>
            <option value=46>46</option>
            <option value=47>47</option>
            <option value=48>48</option>
            <option value=49>49</option>
            <option value=50>50</option>
            <option value=51>51</option>
            <option value=52>52</option>
            <option value=53>53</option>
            <option value=54>54</option>
            <option value=55>55</option>
            <option value=56>56</option>
            <option value=57>57</option>
            <option value=58>58</option>
            <option value=59>59</option>
        </select>
        </li>
        <li class='point'>:</li>
        <li class='sec'>
            <select>
            <option value=0>00</option>
            <option value=1>01</option>
            <option value=2>02</option>
            <option value=3>03</option>
            <option value=4>04</option>
            <option value=5>05</option>
            <option value=6>06</option>
            <option value=7>07</option>
            <option value=8>08</option>
            <option value=9>09</option>
            <option value=10>10</option>
            <option value=11>11</option>
            <option value=12>12</option>
            <option value=13>13</option>
            <option value=14>14</option>
            <option value=15>15</option>
            <option value=16>16</option>
            <option value=17>17</option>
            <option value=18>18</option>
            <option value=19>19</option>
            <option value=20>20</option>
            <option value=21>21</option>
            <option value=22>22</option>
            <option value=23>23</option>
            <option value=24>24</option>
            <option value=25>25</option>
            <option value=26>26</option>
            <option value=27>27</option>
            <option value=28>28</option>
            <option value=29>29</option>
            <option value=30>30</option>
            <option value=31>31</option>
            <option value=32>32</option>
            <option value=33>33</option>
            <option value=34>34</option>
            <option value=35>35</option>
            <option value=36>36</option>
            <option value=37>37</option>
            <option value=38>38</option>
            <option value=39>39</option>
            <option value=40>40</option>
            <option value=41>41</option>
            <option value=42>42</option>
            <option value=43>43</option>
            <option value=44>44</option>
            <option value=45>45</option>
            <option value=46>46</option>
            <option value=47>47</option>
            <option value=48>48</option>
            <option value=49>49</option>
            <option value=50>50</option>
            <option value=51>51</option>
            <option value=52>52</option>
            <option value=53>53</option>
            <option value=54>54</option>
            <option value=55>55</option>
            <option value=56>56</option>
            <option value=57>57</option>
            <option value=58>58</option>
            <option value=59>59</option>
        </select>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            digitalClock();
        });

        function digitalClock() {
            hrs = $(".hours option")
            min = $(".min option")
            sec = $(".sec option")

            var _updateTime = function() {
                s = new Date().getUTCSeconds();
                m = new Date().getUTCMinutes();
                h = new Date().getUTCHours();
                sec.removeAttr("selected").eq(s).attr("selected", "");
                min.removeAttr("selected").eq(m).attr("selected", "");
                hrs.removeAttr("selected").eq(h).attr("selected", "");
            };

            setInterval(_updateTime, 1000);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here's still setting 0, but the new version of jQuery solved the problem for now...

Answer (score 0):

try include the js code in header, it seems is the initialize time(doc ready) affect the result

```
<head>
<!-- JavaScript Includes -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    digitalClock();
});

function digitalClock() {
    hrs = $(".hours option")
    min = $(".min option")
    sec = $(".sec option")

    var _updateTime = function() {
        s = new Date().getUTCSeconds();
        m = new Date().getUTCMinutes();
        h = new Date().getUTCHours();
        sec.removeAttr("selected").eq(s).attr("selected", "");
        min.removeAttr("selected").eq(m).attr("selected", "");
        hrs.removeAttr("selected").eq(h).attr("selected", "");
    };

    setInterval(_updateTime, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>
```